# curl https ssl certificate problem error #35

Tags: php, ssl, curl

I have a machine with https address and authentication with user and pass and Invalid ssl . So i can connect that with linux command line :

```
curl -k --anyauth -u username:password -d '{"flag":"all"}' -H "Content-Type:application/json" https://example.com
```

But I can not connect that with this php :

```
$curl=curl_init();
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_URL, 'https://example.com');
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_HTTPAUTH, CURLAUTH_ANY ) ;
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, array("Content-type:application/json;"));
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_USERPWD, "username:password");
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION, 1);
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, 0);
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYHOST, 0);
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_VERBOSE, 0);
$content = curl_exec($curl);
```

when I try to connect that with php I have this error :

```
Curl failed with error #35: error:14094410:SSL routines:ssl3_read_bytes:sslv3 alert handshake failure
```

Comment: This could be anything: no common TLS  protocol, no shared cipher, missing client certificate ... . It is not related to the server certificate though so disabling certificate verification will not help.  Since it works with command line curl but not with PHP curl might be caused by both having a different backend and/or version. Please provide details of `curl --version` and [curl_version](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.curl-version.php).

Comment: @SteffenUllrich thank you for comment. I check curl version in command line and that is :curl 7.29.0 and i check curl version in phpinfo() and that is 7.72.0 .

Comment: So now you have at least an explanation why curl command line and PHP behave differently - because they are different versions. Given that the older version works while the newer version not I would expect the problem to be in the security settings of the server: the older version of curl might accept weaker protocols and/or ciphers than the newer one. This is only speculation though. To be more helpful one would need the detailed version information provided by curl (command line and PHP) and not just the version number. One would also need to know the target domain which causes the problems.

Comment: @SteffenUllrich so I think curl must be downgrade for php to version 7.29 . may some change require in target domain ? i can access other domain with curl in php. for test i run another domain with an invalid ssl and i can access that with curl in php.

Comment: Please see my comment on what information I need to provide more details about the cause of the problem. Only if I know what caused the issue I can make recommendations on fix or work around it.

Comment: Ok.Thanks for help.this is return from command line :
curl 7.29.0 (x86_64-redhat-linux-gnu) libcurl/7.29.0 NSS/3.44 zlib/1.2.7 libidn/                                                                                                 1.28 libssh2/1.8.0
Protocols: dict file ftp ftps gopher http https imap imaps ldap ldaps pop3 pop3s                                                                                                  rtsp scp sftp smtp smtps telnet tftp
Features: AsynchDNS GSS-Negotiate IDN IPv6 Largefile NTLM NTLM_WB SSL libz unix-

Comment: And this is curl info in phpinfo():
cURL support enabled
cURL Information 7.72.0
Age 7
Features
AsynchDNS Yes
CharConv No
Debug No
GSS-Negotiate No
IDN No
IPv6 Yes
krb4 No
Largefile Yes
libz Yes
NTLM Yes
NTLMWB Yes
SPNEGO Yes
SSL Yes
SSPI No
TLS-SRP Yes
HTTP2 Yes
GSSAPI Yes
KERBEROS5 Yes
UNIX_SOCKETS Yes
PSL No
Protocols dict, file, ftp, ftps, gopher, http, https, imap, imaps, pop3, pop3s, rtsp, scp, sftp, smb, smbs, smtp, smtps, telnet, tftp
Host x86_64-redhat-linux-gnu
SSL Version OpenSSL/1.1.1h
ZLib Version 1.2.7
libSSH Version libssh2/1.8.0

Comment: @SteffenUllrich And this is Domain:
https://209.190.16.231/api/query_incoming_sms

Comment: It looks for me like the server has problem with some extensions set by OpenSSL 1.1.1, i.e. the server does not even like the ClientHello (initial record of handshake from client), even if a support cipher and TLS protocol version is used which works with lower versions of OpenSSL.  It might be a problem in the server side TLS stack which according to the banner uses MatrixSSL 3.9.5 which is now 3 years old, i.e. was released a year before OpenSSL 1.1.1. If possible upgrade the server to newer releases.

Answer (score 2):

A possible source of error is that the client tries to use SSL3 which is not supported by the server.

You could try forcing TLS1.0 with `curl_setopt ($ch, CURLOPT_SSLVERSION, CURL_SSLVERSION_TLSv1_0);` and see if it helps.

Comment: Very unlikely. The `sslv3` in OpenSSL error message usually do not mean that SSL 3.0 is actually used but that the same code base is used which also implements SSL 3.0.